# Facebook SDK 500Internal server error

Tags: facebook, sdk

I new to IIS 7.5 and I need to integrate the Facebook SDK.

I not sure something to do with the php_curl or not but you can view the phpinfo http://goo.gl/ODQqR and I using the default example.php here http://goo.gl/STF7Z

This server is live so I can't risk to test and restart.

I have also enabled error_reporting(E_ALL); but it didn't display any useful message.

Please help me!

-

Update:

If I remove those `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');` then it work.

Does this means I need to configure something from the facebook app setting?

Comment: Please add the error message that you have received when you enabled `error_reporting`

Comment: Look into the server's error log.

Comment: I new to this IIS and I read the C:\Windows\temp\php53_errors.log the last line is date few month ago. Sorry to ask this but where do I read the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can't be identified, end up I written a ugly api instead of using official facebook API.